# Fundamental theorem of calculus for multivariable function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

In a proof, they have written: $$\frac{f(x,y+t)-f(x,y)}{t}=\int_0^1 f_y(x,y+st)ds$$
But doesnt the fundamental theorem of calculus say $$\int_0^1 f_y(x,y+st)ds=f(x,y+t)-f(x,y)?$$
I'm sure the answer is obvious, but for the life of me I can't see where this extra $1/t$ coming from.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that your version can't be right: taking $t=0$ gives $0$ on the right and $f_y(x,y)$ on the left.

Perhaps it is easier to see after a substitution: putting $u=st$, $ds=du/t$ and the integral becomes
$$ \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t f_y(x,y+u) \, du, $$
and the integral can be done using the FToC to give $f(x,y+t)-f(x,y)$.

Essentially, this is the rule that $\int f'(ay) \, dy = \frac{1}{a}f(ay)+C$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Do the substitution $u=st$. The $\frac{1}{t}$ comes from the fact that you have $f_y(x,y+st)$ and not $f_y(x,y+s)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$ \frac{d}{ds} \left( \frac{f(x,y+st)}{t} \right) = \frac{1}{t} f_y (x,y+st) \frac{d}{ds} (y+st) = \frac{1}{t} f_y(x,y+st) t = f_y(x,y+st), $$
then 
$$ \int_0^1 f_y(x,y+st) \, ds = \frac{f(x,y+st)}{t} \Biggr|_{s=0}^{s=1} = \frac{f(x,y+t)-f(x,y)}{t}. $$